# How to compress existing data on a ZFS files system?

Tags: zfs

I have a zfs pool and it already have around 3TB of data. 
I have set the compression=lz4 by running

```
zfs set compression=lz4 secondarystore

root@home:/home/user1# zfs get compression secondarystore
NAME            PROPERTY     VALUE     SOURCE
secondarystore  compression  lz4       local

# zfs get compressratio secondarystore 
NAME            PROPERTY       VALUE  SOURCE
secondarystore  compressratio  1.00x  -
```

Does this compress the existing data or are there any other method of compression using zfs tools ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

moving data out of pool and getting it back to pool compressed those files. 200G-out of pool and back in was 12G

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [a small shell script](http://github.com/gary17/zfs-recompress) to replicate, verify and overwrite all files in the current working directory and all its descendant directories in order to trigger ZFS compression. Use with significant caution and **make sure to have a backup beforehand.**